# Resizing an IE's window given dimensions of renderable space

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, resize

I'm looking to write a function which resizes an IE {7,8,9} window using javascript. The input to the function is the desired size of the rendered webpage (so IE's window without status bar, borders, scrollbars, etc.

Calling foo(120, 100) should result in a rendered web page which is exactly 120px by 100px.

This was my first effort:

```
function foo(x,y) 
{
    window.resizeBy( x - window.document.body.clientWidth, y - window.document.body.clientHeight );
}
```

This works reliabily for the x dimension, but not the y dimension. What is going wrong here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.resizeBy( x - window.documentElement.offsetWidth, y - window.documentElement.offsetHeight );